# How can I make one smaller table that overrides another bigger table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to two table

```
table 1       table 2

id a b c       id a  

1  2 3 a       1  r
2  4 5 b       4  d
3  6 7 c       5  s
4  8 9 d
5  1 2 e
6  2 3 f
```

I want the table2 override table 1.
below is the result I want

***I want to create a view table***

```
table override

id a b c

1  r 3 a
2  4 5 b
3  6 7 c
4  d 9 d
5  s 2 e
6  2 3 f
```

How am I able to do that?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
SET table1.a=table2.a
```

> if You want view try thiz one :

```
select t1.id,ifnull(t2.a,t1.a),t1.b from table_1 as t1 left join table_2 as t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

**Creating View :**

`CREATE VIEW tbl_vw AS SELECT t1.id,COALESCE(t2.a,t1.a),b,c FROM  table_1 as t1 left
JOIN  table_2 as t2 ON  t1.id = t2.id ;`

[Here is a Link for sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1849d/2/0)

Comment: Thanks for you answering. `IFNULL(t2.a,t1.a)` means replace t1.a with t2.a when t2.a is `NULL` right? But t2.a never has `NULL` values. @Hrithu

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 ON t1.id = t2.id SET t1.a = t2.a
```

**Change for View:**

```
    CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT t1.id,COALESCE(t2.a,t1.a),b,c FROM  t1
```

LEFT JOIN  t2 ON  t1.id = t2.id ;

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d20d7/1)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain myself clear. I want to create a view table instead of overwrite `table1`. I've modified my question.

Comment: @llesh Patel Thanks for you answering. `COALESCE(t2.a,t1.a)` means replace t1.a with t2.a when t2.a is `NULL` right? But t2.a never has `NULL` values

Comment: @trueBlue: t2 has only values where there is some ID in t2 and that you also want to override.  t2 has null values for those IDS having value in t1 but not in t2.

Comment: @llesh Patel Thanks for you patient answering. but Hirthu 's answer is more correct. Because the "LEFT JOIN" is very important in my case.

Comment: Yes, I am going to change mine also so in future someone will not missguide from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE with JOIN as shown below

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
SET table1.a=table2.a
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain myself clear. I want to create a view table instead of overwrite `table1`. I've modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help. Sorry because I did not have a chance to run in

```
select case when t.d is null then t.a else t.d end, t.b, t.c
from
(
    select t1.a a, t1.b b , t1.c c, t2.a d
    from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
) t
```